# Qt Designer 5, QLineEdit: enter new text upon dynamically refreshed one

Tags: widget, pyqt, qt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

I use Qt Designer to create GUI for a *Python3* script. One of my priorities is to completely eliminate the manual editing of .*UI*- or .*PY*-files (the latter - obtained with the *pyuic*).

One of the task is to change the data, dynamically renewed in some text field of a widget. It goes so:

There is a widget, let it be *QLineEdit*. The main program (*Python* script) receives data from an external device and writes it in the widget. This is a periodic process, e.g. once per 400 ms.

Now I need to enter the new data in this widget. Since there are a lot of such widgets in a main window, I'd prefer to enter the new text *exactly in the same place where old data is displayed* - that is, in the same *QLineEdit* widget.

For example, I set a mouse pointer on the widget, click on it (Event1) and the refreshing stops. I enter new text, press Enter (Event2) and my main script processes the new text. Afterwards the script renews refreshing.

In this sequence I need to get 2 signals from my widget (*QLineEdit* in our case). The problem is that the *QLineEdit* has not clicked() signal. I could add such a signal (and I did it in Qt4) - but only manually, editing .*PY*-file. As I mentioned, it is highly undesirable.

Is there another signal I could use? Is there another widget? Is there another sequence of entering new data upon the dynamic data?

UPD: I know about *event* methods: *mousePressEvent()* or *focusInEvent()*. I can emit signal with the use of these methods. But it means manual editing of .UI-file. Maybe somebody shows how to add a signal in a Configure Connection window of Qt Designer - since the *Edit* key is not active...

Comment: As explained in the accepted answer to the linked question, you can use either event filtering or widget promotion.